# Chrome extension icon has a yellow / orange highlighted background / border

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've loaded an unpacked extension in chrome. The icon has an unwanted yellow/orange background where it was supposed to be transparent. If I fill the transparent color, it still has a yellow/orange border. Is it a new update in Chrome that indicates an unpacked extension or is it indicating a security issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it has to do with unpacked extension as [mentioned here](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/FqT82A5xPxa)

> Chrome extensions that are in developer mode (loaded from the command
>   line or as **unpacked** extensions from chrome://extensions) will now be
>   **highlighted** with an **orange background** on Windows.
>
> This change will target Windows Beta and Stable but you can have it
>   now by running the last chromium build with the
>   --enable-force-dev-mode-highlighting switch¹.
>
> ¹ http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

**Update :** Verified, that if you pack the extension & install it, the highlight goes away. The extension doesn't have to come from Chrome store. Even if the packed extension is installed from the desktop (drag & drop on the browser), it's fine. I'm guessing it has to do with signing the integrity of the extension. If a malware tries to muck with it, the packed extension would become invalid. Whereas it's relatively simple to tamper an unpacked extension.

It's very easy to pack an extension, no external tools needed : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging